# Find a pattern in middle of multiple sentences

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataframe as below,

```
data = [
    [ 1, 'AR-123456' ],
    [ 1, '123456' ],
    [ 2, '345678' ],
    [ 3,'Application-12345678901'],
    [ 3, '12345678901']
]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Case', 'ID'] )
```

| Case | ID |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | AR-123456 |
| 1 | 123456 |
| 2 | 345678 |
| 3 | Application-12345678901 |
| 3 | 12345678901 |

So basically I am trying to remove rows where for the same Case, the IDs are digits from AR- or Application- i.e., the final expected output :-

| Case | ID |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | AR-123456 |
| 2 | 345678 |
| 3 | Application-12345678901 |

Answer (score 1):

Extract the digits and `drop_duplicates`:

```
df["digits"] = df["ID"].str.extract("(\d+)")
output = df.drop_duplicates(["Case","digits"]).drop("digits",axis=1)

>>> output
   Case                       ID
0     1                AR-123456
2     2                   345678
3     3  Application-12345678901
```

Comment: What if `AR-123456` is after `123456` and `Application-12345678901` is before `Application-12345678901`?

Comment: @Ynjxsjmh good point, missed that detail

Answer (score 0):

You can groupby `Case` column and then drop the duplicated `ID` rows that is in `AR`/`Application` item

```py
out = (df.groupby('Case')
       .apply(lambda g: g[~g['ID'].isin(g['ID'].str.extract('(AR|Application)-(\d+)')[1])])
       .reset_index(drop=True))
```

```
print(out)

   Case                       ID
0     1                AR-123456
1     2                   345678
2     3  Application-12345678901
```